apache spark `--files` option writing to local disk
I am running the following command trying to submit my job to Kubernetes using Apache Spark .
spark-submit --master k8s://https://fqdn_to_k8s:6443 \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--name  my_job_name \
--files /path/to/hbase-site.xml \
--class my.class.name \
--driver-memory 4g \
--conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=my_namespace \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=my_image \
--conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true \
--conf spark.eventLog.dir=file:///opt/spark/logs/spark \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
--conf spark.kubernetes.file.upload.path=/opt/file-upload \
--conf spark.history.fs.logDirectory=file:///opt/spark/logs/spark \
--conf spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-history-pvc.options.claimName=spark-history-pvc \
--conf spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-history-pvc.mount.path=/opt/spark/logs/spark \
--conf spark.kubernetes.driver.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-history-pvc.mount.readOnly=false \
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-history-pvc.options.claimName=spark-history-pvc \
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-history-pvc.mount.path=/opt/spark/logs/spark \
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.volumes.persistentVolumeClaim.spark-history-pvc.mount.readOnly=false \
local:////opt/rollup/my.jar

The job errors out with the following:
Files file:/opt/file-upload/spark-upload-c806cc60-a035-4b87-9ad0-b4f4f3e6a21d/hbase-site.xml from /opt/file-upload/spark-upload-c806cc60-a035-4b87-9ad0-b4f4f3e6a21d/hbase-site.xml to /opt/spark/work-dir/hbase-site.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /opt/file-upload/spark-upload-c806cc60-a035-4b87-9ad0-b4f4f3e6a21d/hbase-site.xml
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:106)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.copy(UnixCopyFile.java:548)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.copy(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:257)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.copy(Files.java:1305)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$14(SparkSubmit.scala:441)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:286)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:279)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.downloadResourcesToCurrentDirectory$1(SparkSubmit.scala:429)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$16(SparkSubmit.scala:450)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:450)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:964)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1120)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1129)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

The issue is that I need to have the hbase-site.xml file available in the executors.  I thought by using --files and --deploy-mode cluster this should upload the file to the driver and executors running in k8s.  However, what I am seeing is it creating a directory and moving the hbase-site.xml file on the machine I am submitting from.  Why is it using the node that I am submitting from at all?  It is not part of the k8s cluster and I am using --deploy-mode cluster.  Am I missing another setting somewhere?

you cannot "upload a local file" with spark submit - instead you need to upload the files to a shared filesystem (s3, hdfs, etc.), and provide spark-submit the path with the full schema (s3://foo/bar)
